# How to set post content's first image to be thumbnail image for more than 1000 records?

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, posts

Good day, I'm having more than 1000 posts imported from the CSV files so most of them don't have featured images. I've try installing the plugins which help automatically updated the featured images based on the post content but they're not working in Wordpress 4.9.7. 
Is there any solution or plugin that helps me to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use plugins, so you can get the solution on same-

**First Plugin - Sharing the plugin link, follow the link -**  [WordPress Importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/)

Second Plugin - Sharing the plugin link, follow the link - [Auto Upload Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-upload-images/#reviews)

Hope!! it's useful for you..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a plugin for that but here is the code if you want to do it yourself
you will need to collect the posts IDs in an array lets say "posts_ids"

```
$posts_ids = array();
foreach ( $posts_ids as $post_id ) {
    $attachments = get_attached_media( 'image', $post_id );
    if ( ! empty( $attachments ) ) {
        set_post_thumbnail( $post_id , array_keys( $attachments )[0] );
    }
}
```